# Changing Elif Statement to "Python-Like" Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

I have the understanding that Python is all about efficiency.
How would I write the code below to be more Pythonic?

I thought of using a dictionary, but since the conditions for the `elif` statement are ranges, I don't think that's possible.

```py
threshold_scale
if pop in range(threshold_scale[0], threshold_scale[1]):
    color = '#ff0000'
elif pop in range(threshold_scale[1], threshold_scale[2]):
    color = '#f6ff00'
elif pop in range(threshold_scale[2], threshold_scale[3]):
    color = '#00ff08'
elif pop in range(threshold_scale[3], threshold_scale[4]):
    color = '#0d00ff'
elif pop in range(threshold_scale[4], threshold_scale[5]+1):
    color = '#ff00f7'
```

**Output**

`[1960, 648065, 1294170, 1940275, 2586380, 3232486]`

Comment: "Python is all about efficiency" ?? Since when? What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Efficiency-wise there is nothing wrong with this code. `in range(...)` is an O(1) check, and `elif` makes sure that only the minimal number of checks will be done.

Comment: And, FWIW, `range` objects **are** hashable, so they **can** be used as dictionary keys

Comment: I think dictionary is not a bad choice here.

Comment: I didn't know range can be used in dictionaries, because all the dictionary examples I find are using string objects. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: You can use a `range` as a key, but dict lookup is still based on *equality*, not containment, so you would still have to iterate overs the keys to check if `pop` is in each range.

Comment: This is an example where an *interval tree* would make the most sense (though there is no interval tree data structure in the Python standard library).  See, for example, https://pypi.org/project/intervaltree/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) is designed for these types of queries. One example is the [`intervaltree`](https://pypi.org/project/intervaltree/) module.

```
from intervaltree import IntervalTree, Interval

threshold_scale = [1960, 648065, 1294170, 1940275, 2586380, 3232486]

ranges = zip(threshold_scale, threshold_scale[1:])
colors = ["#ff0000", "#f6ff00", "$00ff08", "$0d00ff", "$ff00f7"]

t = IntervalTree([Interval(x, y, c) for (x,y), c in zip(ranges, colors)])

pop = 2000

color = sorted(t[2000])[0].data
```

For `n` intervals, it takes `O(n lg n)` to build the interval tree, and a single query takes `O(lg n)` time. (Technically, it's `O(lg n + m)`, where `m` is the number of items in the result. Our tree consists of non-overlapping ranges, though, so `m` always equals 1.)

By comparison, your `if` statement would take `O(n)` time. Each `pop in range(...)` takes `O(1)` time, but there could be `O(n)` of them. Using an interval tree is faster if you need to make many queries against the same set of intervals.

Answer (score 1):

```
colors = [
    '#ff0000',
    '#f6ff00',
    '#00ff08',
    '#0d00ff',
    '#ff00f7',
]
color = next(c for c, t_range in
             zip(colors, zip(threshold_scale, threshold_scale[1:])) if
             pop in range(*t_range))
```

Given input:

```
threshold_scale = [0,2,4,6,8,10]
pop = 7
```

Outputs:

```
f6ff00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.digitize](http://file:///home/mints/.local/share/Zeal/Zeal/docsets/NumPy.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/doc/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html#numpy.digitize)

```
import numpy as np

threshold_scale = [1960, 648065, 1294170, 1940275, 2586380, 3232486]

pop = [2000, 2000000, 2800000]

color = np.array(['#ff0000', '#f6ff00', '#00ff08', '#0d00ff', '#ff00f7'])

color[np.digitize(pop, threshold_scale) - 1]
```

You will have to deal with pop values outside of covered range too...